# Imported CommonJS (CJS) into ES Module (MJS) leads to "TypeError: module is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I'm trying to migrate from CommonJS (.cjs) to ES Modules (.mjs). To do that I replaced:

```js
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
```

with

```js
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
```

within the ES Module.

Now, when try to execute the code:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    param: val
}));
```

I get an error:

> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
>
> TypeError: bodyParser.urlencoded is not a function
>
> ```
> at file:///…/app.mjs:44:20
> at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:110:37)
> at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:176:24)
> ```

I googled for this error and most of the answers reference to a need to require the `body-parser` component. But in my case I do it already with:

```js
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
```

Any idea why do I still get such issue although the module is imported? Can it be due to asynchronous nature of ES Modules imports? Perhaps, should I wait until all imported modules are really imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```js
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
```

Comment: Now I have another but similar issue: `TypeError: app.use is not a function`.

Comment: If you're using `express`, you must also import `express` this way: `import express from "express";` and then create the `app` object the usual way (e.g.: `const app = express();`).

Comment: Is there any difference between `import * as %module% from %module%` and `import %module% from %module%`? I assumed it's just a way to assign an alias, isn't?

Comment: When you import CommonJS modules you must use `import module from "module";`.
It's written in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interoperability_with_commonjs).

Comment: Thanks for the link. What's interesting, for the `fs` I use `import * as fs from "fs";` and it _does_ work, although it is a CJS, as far as I understand.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with default export or something. I honestly don't know the detailed inner workings of how the different types of modules are handled. I just follow the docs.

P.S.: the ES6 modules are experimental, so maybe when they become stable, more clarity will be exposed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210488/discussion-between-mike-b-and-luca-polito).